# Shading grid which is fully inside slips

Tags: shading, grids, tikz-pic

I have an ellipse  drawn over a grid of small square, I need to shade those square in which are fully inside the ellipse, is there is way to do it without trying to shade one by one for each square?
Here is what I get when I run the code below
[image]
Here is the code:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{pgf,tikz}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
\definecolor{cqcqcq}{rgb}{0.7529411764705882,0.7529411764705882,0.7529411764705882}
\begin{tikzpicture}[line cap=round,line join=round,>=triangle 45,x=1.0cm,y=1.0cm]
\draw [color=cqcqcq,, xstep=0.2cm,ystep=0.2cm] (1.6545364855997213,0.21463161817165122) grid (10.69837464681328,7.590037566885466);
\clip(1.6545364855997213,0.21463161817165122) rectangle (10.69837464681328,7.590037566885466);
\draw [rotate around={90.:(5.,4.)}] (5.,3.) ellipse (2.5617375054936047cm and 1.6007807617074208cm);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

but I need to my graph to look like this:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that normal clipping will not work, because clipping does not know anything about the grid. The following example combines the clipping with the ellipse as clipping area with excluding cells, which intersects with the ellipse.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}
\definecolor{cqcqcq}{RGB}{192,192,192}
\colorlet{square}{blue!75!white}

\begin{tikzpicture}

  \def\xmin{3.8}
  \def\xmax{8.2}
  \def\ymin{1}
  \def\ymax{7}

  \def\EllipsePath{%
    [rotate around={90:(5, 4)}]
    (5, 3) ellipse (2.5617375054936047cm and 1.6007807617074208cm)%
  }
  \path[name path=ellipse]\EllipsePath;

  \global\let\FillList\empty

  \foreach \x in {4.4, 4.6, ..., 7.6} {
    \foreach \y in {1.4, 1.6, ..., 6.4} {
      \path[name path=square] (\x, \y) rectangle ++(.2, .2);
      \path[name intersections={
          of=ellipse and square,
          total=\t,
      }]
        \pgfextra{
          \ifnum\t=0 %
            \xdef\FillList{%
              \FillList
              \ifx\FillList\empty\else,\fi
              \x/\y%
            }%
          \fi
        }
      ;
    }
  }
  \begin{scope}
    \clip\EllipsePath;
    \fill[square]
      \foreach \x/\y in \FillList {
        (\x, \y) rectangle ++(.2, .2)
      }
    ;
  \end{scope}

  \draw[color=cqcqcq, step=.2]
    (\xmin, \ymin) grid (\xmax, \ymax)
    (\xmin, \ymin) rectangle (\xmax, \ymax)
  ;
  \clip (\xmin, \ymin) rectangle (\xmax, \ymax);
  \draw\EllipsePath;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Caution: Compilation need quite some time.

> [image: Result]

Comment: changing the final `\y` value from 6.2 to 6.4 is needed to fill some more squares near the top of the ellipse:`\foreach \y in {1.4, 1.6, ..., 6.4}`. I can't believe how long this takes to compile.

Comment: @corporal There is room for optimization: Calculation of the fill area could be done by a faster external program. I have already optimized the number of fill operations: one fill operation with a path consisting of the cells. These cells could be merged to a polygon for the outline.